# Modificar propiedades de una imagen generada por Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

Tengo una imagen generada desde javascript a la que le he dado su respectiva src
El problema es que he tenido que modificar su tamaño y para que se vea como quiero tengo que aplicarle un image-rendering: pixelated, pero no encuentro manera de seleccionar la imagen para darle la propiedad, ni en css ni desde el mismo javascript.

He probado a darle una clase a la imagen y seleccionarla desde css pero tampoco me ha funcionado

```
const image = new Image()
image.src = './img/mapaeste.png'
image.classList.add("mapa")


context.fillStyle = 'blue'
context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height )

image.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(image, -130 , -130)
}
```

```
.mapa{
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```
<canvas></canvas>
<script src = "index.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: hace falta un ejemplo mas concreto.

Comment: No se a que te refieres con un ejemplo más concreto. Simplemente no puedo seleccionar la imagen para aplicarle las propiedades y no sé muy bien por qué

Comment: Lo que puede estar sucediendo son varias cosas, 1) que la clase no se este aplicando a la imagen o 2) que primero carga el css y luego el sistema agrega la imagen y no aplique las reglas css, no recuerdo si este ultimo afecta que primero carge el css y luego los elementos, pero es una posibilidad

Comment: Tiene que ser que primero carga el css y después javascript , ya que al hacer console.log(image) sale con la clase. Aún así sigo sin saber como solucionarlo...

Comment: hay infromacion que estas omitiendo por ejemplo de donde sale canvas???
no veo donde se asigna en el codigo, una cosa es un tag html otra un tag cavas, se manipulan de distintaforma.

Comment: ya he puesto el html

Comment: Puedes crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable en la propia pregunta insertando un snippet con el botón que indica <>